# Rename axes in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm plotting a graph via plotly, and I'm trying to rename my axes.

This is my code, with date, variable and value being columns in my file:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~date, y = ~variable, z = ~value)
```

and this is my graph:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp0GT.png)

I'm trying to rename value, variable, date. Can you help me achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading the [manual](https://plotly.com/r/figure-labels/) a bit more carfully before posting questions here. However, this should help you:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~date, y = ~variable, z = ~value) %>% layout(
     scene = list(
         xaxis = list(title = "some X label"),
         yaxis = list(title = "some Y label"),
         zaxis = list(title = "some Z label")
     ))
```